# Filter a LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-objects

Here's my query.

```
var query = from g in dc.Group
            join gm in dc.GroupMembers on g.ID equals gm.GroupID
            where gm.UserID == UserID
            select new {
                id = g.ID,
                name = g.Name,
                pools = (from pool in g.Pool
                // more stuff to populate pools
```

So I have to perform some filtering, but when I attempt to filter

```
var filter = query.Where(f => f.pools.[no access to list of columns]
```

I can't access any of the items within "pools".  Does anyone know how I'm able to access that?

What I'd like to do is this:

```
var filterbyGame = query.Where(f = > f.pools.GameName == "TestGame");
```

Let me know if that's even possible with thew ay I have this setup.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Of course, `pools` is a collection of pool objects. In itself, it doesn't have `GameName` property. How do you want to perform the matching? Match all objects in query that has at least a single pool with the `GameName` specified? Or match the ones that for all of their pools `GameName` is identical to the argument?

Comment: Match all the pools that have the same GameName.  so just return the pools where the gamename is called "Mega" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pools` is an enumeration, not a single instance. That's why you're not getting column names.

You need to change your filter to something like:

```
var filterByGame = query.Where(f => f.pools.Any(p => p.GameName == "TestGame"));
```

Comment: so I tried this;
var test =  query.Where(f => f.pools.Any(p => p.GameName == "Test"));  doesn't work.

Comment: @Jack Marchetti - Are you sure that f.pools contained a GameName match? Always double check and make sure.

Comment: Yep I'm positive.  I did a copy and past eon the == "GameName"  I even tried doing a .ToLower() just in case.

Answer (score 4):

In your query you can't do Where(f => f.pools.GameName)
because f is an IEnumerable<>

Something like this should work:

```
Where(f => f.pools.Any(p => p.GameName == "TestGame"))
```